# Can't update the value of textview by settext

Tags: android, settext

My settext do not update after I have updated it's value from database. But if I logout and login into my app settext is refreshed.I get the value of settext by SharedPreferences.

public class MySettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private TextView settingsDisplayName;
private TextView settingsDisplayStatus;

private User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUser();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_settings);

    settingsDisplayName = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.settings_username);
    settingsDisplayStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settings_status);



    settingsChangeUsername.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String old_name = settingsDisplayName.getText().toString();
            Intent usernameIntent = new Intent(MySettingsActivity.this, UsernameActivity.class);
            usernameIntent.putExtra("user_name",old_name );
            startActivity(usernameIntent);

        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onStart() {


    MySettingsActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            settingsDisplayName.setText(user.getName());

            settingsDisplayStatus.setText(user.getEmail());
        }
    });
    super.onStart();
}
```

}

Comment: where do you trigger your runnable?

Comment: @Nikos Hidalgo in onStart method

Comment: @Nikos Hidalgo I also tried to do it on onCreate method but nothing changing

Comment: provided that you are fetching the shared preferences correctly, are you sure that there's a value stored when you run the runnable? I would use breakpoints to see the results you're getting. Also, it would help if you would include more of the relevant code

Comment: @NikosHidalgo Yes I'm sure that there is a value stored in my database. When I register it stores my data into database and settext shows me my name. But when i update my username the value in my database changes but the value of the settext doesn't.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo also I have another activity which shows all users of the application. And if I change my username int allsuers activity my username changes. I think all problem is in my first activity

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I have edited my code